# Weird behavior with gcc 4.9.2 on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, gcc

I've been debugging a black texture problem on some code that works on Windows for some days and today I found out it might not be related to how I handle openGL calls.. the following snippet of code contains a `std::cout` line.

If I comment out the `cout` line, I get the black texture. If I leave it in the code, I get the texture rendered correctly.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> png_data;

loadPNG("texture.png", width, height, format, png_data);

// COMMENT LINE!
// std::cout << "First RGBA value is " << std::hex << png_data[0] << " " << png_data[1] << " " << png_data[2] << " " << png_data[3] << std::endl;

glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, png_data.data());
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a compiler issue?

Comment: If you can't immediately squeeze out reputation from this question and you're frustrated for the 2 minutes you spent reading and understanding it, don't closevote but explain why you think this isn't worth asking or answering.

Comment: How can this be answered without seeing a complete example that exhibits the problem? What does `loadPNG` do, for a start? It's almost certainly UB in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @AlanStokes It's too long to post it here, [here's the function I'm using](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ahrs-visualizer/blob/master/png_texture.cpp)

Comment: Comment out `loadPNG` and initialize `png` data to a known simple image, like a green square.

Comment: @n.m. [this](http://pastebin.com/QsRNajje) prints a nice red square with and without the cout line

Comment: Then your problem is probably in `loadPNG` or at some point before that. Use `valgrind` to hunt down memory errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a compiler issue.

This is a classical example of undefined behavior/corrupted memory. At some point before your code reached this part, a bug ends up corrupting the heap, or the stack, by running off the end of an array, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, or countless of other examples of undefined behavior.

The nature of the corruption isn't severe enough to result in an immediate segfault or a crash, at that point, but code execution continues until you get to this part. At this point, depending on random factors, of which code alignmnt and additional C++ library calls, which themselves are likely to involve heap allocation, is sufficient enough to trigger visible results of undefined behavior, that you're observing here.

There is no single, universal recipe, for identifying the real bug, I'm afraid. It's going to be a combination of trial and error, and using instrumentation tools, like valgrind, to identify and isolate the real bug. [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which is available on your Linux distribution, has a good track record of identifying and locating these kinds of bugs.

Comment: Turns out I had a stack corruption some frames before. Way too hard to debug it on stackoverflow, I had to spend some time myself. Thanks!!